# windows API function

Tags: c#, winapi

I want to use the windows API function-
findwindowex

Can a breakdown of the types of class-s function can have, 
and what things belong to a class.
Thanks,
Ariel

Comment: What is your question?  it's not clear to me on this viewing.

Comment: Are you after a list of windows class names? Stock classes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633574(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

[PInvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.findwindowex) will show you how to setup your P/Invoke so that you can call the method from managed code (assuming that's what you want to know.)

Answer (score 1):

pinvoke.net is a great site for familiarizing yourself with WIN32 APIs, or for reference, complete with sample usages.

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.findwindowex

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to understand your question, but [this link](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.FindWindowEx) shows how it is possible to call `FindWindowEx` from C# application.

Basically, you declare it like that:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
 static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
```

and then call it:

```
handle = FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "WindowName", IntPtr.Zero);
```

Answer (score 0):

A great source of information for calling windows APIs from c# is the [pinvoke](http://pinvoke.net/) site.

It has a list of the api's, examples of how to use most.  And it also has other options in .net for several APIs